# Annotation processing with kapt for debug variant

Tags: android, kapt

I try to use `kapt` for debug variant only. 
In case of `annotationProcessor` there is possibility to write something like this:

```
debugAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:version-number'
```

Where `debug` prefix means that we want to add this dependency only for `debug` variant.

Is there any alternative for `kapt`? I can't use `debugKapt` because it doesn't work.

Comment: You're partially right, it should be `kaptDebug`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to this but I want to extend little bit the answer for the following case:

Case: Multiple variants and to load some dependencies according to selected variant flavor?

Variants: free, paid
Build types: debug, release

For Free I want to load specific dependencies which should not be loaded for Paind when doing the build.

Do it like this (for all cases, depending what you need.):

```
freeImplementation("....")
freeAnnotationProcessor("....")
kaptFree("...")
```

or for a debug case

```
freeImplementationDebug("....")
freeAnnotationProcessorDebug("....")
kaptFreeDebug("...")
```